# SQL (server 2016) - Using the result of a CASE as where-clause of a sub-query

Tags: sql, subquery, case, where-clause, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I have a select-statement with a CASE. This CASE gives back a country-code. In the same select-statement I would like to query another table to retrieve the description which goes with this country-code. In order to do so I have created a subquery. In this subquery I want to use the result of the case in the where-clause.

```
SELECT
      DelAddrCode
    , CASE   WHEN DelAddrCode = '0' THEN (SELECT Customeraddress.countrycode FROM Customeraddress WHERE Customeraddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID)
                                    ELSE (SELECT Deliveryaddress.countrycode FROM Deliveryaddress where Deliveryaddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID AND Deliveryaddress.DelAddrCode = Salesorder.DelAddrCode)
             END AS delivery_country
    , (SELECT country.description from Country WHERE Country.countrycode = delivery_country)
FROM Salesorder
```

The logic here is that you have a default customer address, for instance in the US, but you can deliver a sales order on a different address like the UK. So first I retrieve the DelAddrCode. If 0 then I retrieve the countrycode from the CustomerAdress table. If not 0, then I will get the countrycode from the Deliveryaddress table.

Now that I have the countrycode I would like to get the country description from the Country table. I use a subquery for this. But the where-clause of this subquery depends on the result of the CASE. The above query gives an error: "Invalid column name 'del_country'".

The solution I found is to copy past the case and put it in the subquery:

```
SELECT
      DelAddrCode
    , CASE   WHEN DelAddrCode = '0' THEN (SELECT Customeraddress.countrycode FROM Customeraddress WHERE Customeraddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID)
                                    ELSE (SELECT Deliveryaddress.countrycode FROM Deliveryaddress where Deliveryaddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID AND Deliveryaddress.DelAddrCode = Salesorder.DelAddrCode)
             END AS delivery_country
    , (SELECT country.description from Country WHERE Country.countrycode = 
             (CASE   WHEN DelAddrCode = '0' THEN (SELECT Customeraddress.countrycode FROM Customeraddress WHERE Customeraddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID)
                                            ELSE (SELECT Deliveryaddress.countrycode FROM Deliveryaddress WHERE Deliveryaddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID and Deliveryaddress.DelAddrCode = Salesorder.DelAddrCode)
                     END))
    FROM Salesorder
```

This gives me the result I want, but it makes the code a mess. Is there a way I can refer to the result of the CASE in the subquery to get the same result without having to copy-paste the same CASE again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of `JOIN`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It contains the `CASE` just once and I find it more readable.

```
SELECT t.delAddrCode,
       country.description
FROM
(
    SELECT Salesorder.DelAddrCode,
           CASE
               WHEN Salesorder.DelAddrCode = '0' THEN Customeraddress.countrycode
               ELSE Deliveryaddress.countrycode
           END AS delivery_country
    FROM Salesorder
    LEFT JOIN Customeraddress ON Customeraddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID
    LEFT JOIN Deliveryaddress ON Deliveryaddress.CustID = Salesorder.CustID
            AND Deliveryaddress.DelAddrCode = Salesorder.DelAddrCode
) t
LEFT JOIN Country ON country.countrycode = t.delivery_country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the address tables and see which one matches with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
  DelAddrCode,
  COALESCE(ca.countrycode, da.countrycode) AS countrycode,
  c.description
FROM Salesorder so
LEFT JOIN Customeraddress ca ON ca.CustID = so.CustID AND so.DelAddrCode = 0
LEFT JOIN Deliveryaddress da ON da.CustID = so.CustID AND da.DelAddrCode = so.DelAddrCode
JOIN country c ON c.countrycode = COALESCE(ca.countrycode, da.countrycode);
```

If `Deliveryaddress.DelAddrCode` cannot be 0 (which I assume), you can even make this

```
JOIN country c ON c.countrycode IN (ca.countrycode, da.countrycode);
```

which may lead to a better execution plan for being a simpler link.